# Reachability with Address - Server AND Port - iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ping, reachability

I am trying to check whether a server is online or offline: I face the problem that it has a port when connecting to it

My code at the moment:

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(25667);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("fr7.mooshroom.net");

Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&address];
```

Please let me know what im doing wrong. And please dont link me to other questions, I have searched and none of them have what I'm looking for.

Comment: I am suspecting the input parameter to the function inet_addr, can you replace that with ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it now, i needed to put the line:
`const char *serverIPChar = [serverIP cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`
and replace the "fr7.mooshroom.net" inside the `inet_addr` to `serverIPChar`. Thanks anyway

Comment: Why -1 an answer which fixed it?

Comment: Maybe they didn't understand your answer? So are you using an IP address now? I didn't give you a negative point, that would cost me too much. ;-) I think you didn't offer an answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Basically the inet_addr() function does not do domain name resolution for you.  You need to pass it an IP address (for example 127.0.0.1).

To resolve a DNS name into an IP address you need to look at the standard gethostbyname() functions.

To clarify:

```
struct hostent *host = gethostbyname("fr7.mooshroom.net");
if (host) {
    struct in_addr in;
    NSLog(@"HOST: %s" , host->h_name);
    while (*host->h_addr_list)
    {
        bcopy(*host->h_addr_list++, (char *) &in, sizeof(in));
        NSLog(@"IP: %s", inet_ntoa(in));
    }
}
```

Now, having said all that, are you sure this is going to do what you want?  Documentation for SCNetworkReachabilityRef suggests not:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html

> "A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an
>   application into the network stack, can leave the local device.
>   Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be
>   received by the host."

Comment: I dont need the data to be received by the host, I only need to find out whether its online or offline.

Comment: My point is that you're going to this extra effort of adding the port, but it's not clear that Reachability even uses it.  Understand?

Comment: Hmmm yeah.. you don't understand.  Ahh well.  You're welcome, anyway.

Comment: Oh and I HAVE to add the port, its to check whether a game server is online, the server requires a port to connect to it. Thats why I'm adding the port otherwise I wouldn't do it, I'm not stupid

Comment: But you're not using Reachability to connect to it, are you?

Comment: No i am, I'm using the Reachability by tony million and im using the method `reachabilityWithAddress` to connect to it.

Comment: Ok last comment - That Reachability still uses the SCNetworkReachability framework which I linked to and quoted from above.  If you read the documentation hopefully it will be clearer to you what it does.